# Importing from text file into Java Array

Tags: java, text, import, inputstream

Currently I am trying to import data from a text file regarding pets and doctors, and sending it to my "petArray" and "doctorArray".

I am extremely new to Java and as such am having great difficulty. This is what ive attempted to do, but it doesnt seem too work.

Please see attached Java code and text file (screenshot at link).

```
 public void readFile() {
    String fileName = "VetManagement.txt";
    Scanner inputStream = null;
    try {
        inputStream = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Error opening file: " + fileName);
        System.exit(0);
    }
    while (inputStream.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = inputStream.nextLine();
        String initName = "";
        String initSize = "";
        String initType = "";
        String initDoctor = "";
        double initWeight = 0.0;
        int initAge = 0;

        if (line.equals("Pets")) {
            inputStream.nextLine();

            if (line.equals("type cat")) {
                initType = "cat";
                System.out.print(initType);

            } else if (line.equals("type dog")) {
                initType = "dog";
                System.out.print(initType);
            }

            inputStream.nextLine();

            if (line.equals("size small")) {
                initSize = "small";

            } else if (line.equals("size medium")) {
                initSize = "medium";

            } else if (line.equals("size large")) {
                initSize = "large";

            } else System.out.println("error");

            inputStream.nextLine();

            if (line.startsWith("name")) {
                initName = inputStream.next();

            } else {
                System.out.println("error");
            }

            inputStream.nextLine();

            if (line.startsWith("weight")) {
                initWeight = inputStream.nextDouble();
            } else {
                System.out.println("error");
            }
            inputStream.nextLine();

            if (line.startsWith("age")) {
                initAge = inputStream.nextInt();
            } else {
                System.out.println("error");
            }
            inputStream.nextLine();

            if (line.startsWith("doctor")) {
                initDoctor = inputStream.toString();
            } else {
                System.out.println("error");
            }

            petArray[sumPets] = new Pet();
            petArray[sumPets].setType(initType);
            petArray[sumPets].setSize(initSize);
            petArray[sumPets].setName(initName);
            petArray[sumPets].setWeight(initWeight);
            petArray[sumPets].setAge(initAge);
            petArray[sumPets].setDoctorName(initDoctor);

        } else if (line.equals("Doctors")) ;

    }

    inputStream.close();
}
```

TEXT FILE:

```
Pets
type cat
size small
name Lara
weight 4
age 5
doctor Joao
type dog
size large
name Biro
weight 15
age 12
doctor Maria
type cat
size large
name Benny
weight 7
age 10
doctor no doctor assigned
Doctors
name Joao
specialisation cat
name Maria
specialisation dog
```

Comment: Please copy-paste an excerpt of the text file into the question (as text), instead of linking to an image of the file. You shouldn't touch the stream outside of these lines `while (inputStream.hasNextLine()){ String line = inputStream.nextLine(); ...` Currently you're manipulating the stream inside the loop (with `inputStream.next()` etc), which will cause problems. Instead, process `line` inside the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nextLine` can solve the problem easily no need to over-complicate the work

As the TEXT FILE contains information in format like

```
type cat
size small
name Lara
weight 4
age 5
doctor Joao
```

You can easily store information in desired variable using

```
nextLine = inputStream.nextLine().split(" ");
```

where `nextLine[0]` represent first column and `nextLine[1]` represent second column

I Hope this helps let me know if you have any other problem here is FULL CODE (in case you need)

```
public static void readFile() {
        String fileName = "F:\\document\\eclipse\\JavaAZ\\src\\VetManagement.txt";
        Scanner inputStream = null;
        try {
            inputStream = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Error opening file: " + fileName);
            System.exit(0);
        }
        String[] name = new String[100];
        String[] size = new String[100];
        String[] type = new String[100];
        String[] doctor = new String[100];
        double[] weight = new double[100];
        int[] age = new int[100];
        if (inputStream.hasNextLine()) {
            String[] nextLine = inputStream.nextLine().split(" ");
            int petCounter = 0;
            int doctorCounter = 0;
            String workingArray = new String(nextLine[0]);

            while(inputStream.hasNextLine()) {
                if(workingArray.equals("Pets")) {
                    nextLine = inputStream.nextLine().split(" ");
                    if (nextLine[0].equals("Doctors")) {
                        workingArray = "Doctors";
                        continue;
                    }

                    if (nextLine[0].equals("type")) {
                        type[petCounter] = nextLine[1];
                        //System.out.println(type);
                    }
                    else System.out.println("type error");

                    nextLine = inputStream.nextLine().split(" ");
                    if (nextLine[0].equals("size")) {
                            size[petCounter] = nextLine[1];
                            //System.out.println(size);
                    } 
                    else System.out.println("size error");

                    nextLine = inputStream.nextLine().split(" ");
                    if (nextLine[0].equals("name")) {
                            name[petCounter] = nextLine[1];
                            //System.out.println(name);
                    } 
                    else System.out.println("name error");

                    nextLine = inputStream.nextLine().split(" ");
                    if (nextLine[0].equals("weight")) {
                            weight[petCounter] = Double.parseDouble(nextLine[1]);
                            //System.out.println(weight);
                    } 
                    else System.out.println("weight error"); 

                    nextLine = inputStream.nextLine().split(" ");
                    if (nextLine[0].equals("age")) {
                            age[petCounter] = Integer.parseInt(nextLine[1]);
                            //System.out.println(age);
                    } 
                    else System.out.println("age error"); 

                    nextLine = inputStream.nextLine().split(" ");
                    if (nextLine[0].equals("doctor")) {
                            doctor[petCounter] = nextLine[1];
                            //System.out.println(doctor);
                    } 
                    else System.out.println("doctor error"); 
                    petCounter++;
                }
                else if(workingArray.equals("Doctors")) {
                    // CODE HERE
                    doctorCounter++;
                    break;
                }
            }
         }
        System.out.println("PET NAME: "+name[0]+" and its Weight: "+weight[0]);
        inputStream.close();
    }
```

Comment: sanddy1911, this looks incredible! I'll implement it and have a fiddle and let you know. Thank you very much! +11111

Comment: glad to help :)

Comment: distinguish between where the working array is Doctors or Pets

Comment: this is not the optimal code but it will work fine. I tried hard not to change structure of code so that you can understand easily.

Comment: I'm not sure how I actually save the input to the array. The code youve sent displays it.. so how to I add them to either petArray[sumPets] or doctorArray[sumDoctors]?

Comment: What is the structure of petArray[sumPets]. if it is simple array then you can simply assign values to it.

Comment: Its a very basic array with setters and getters for each attribute of pet, i.e size, type, name, ect..

Comment: then simply assign the values to it.

Comment: if you still didn't figured out how to do that, i'd updated the code.  Check it out

Comment: Managed to get that after your last modifications! Makes perfect sense! thankyou!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
    if (line.equals("Pets")) {
        String nextLine = inputStream.nextLine();
        if (nextLine.equals("type cat")) {
            initType = "cat";
            System.out.print(initType);
        }
        else if (nextLine.equals("type dog")) {
            initType = "dog";
            System.out.print(initType);
        }
        String lineAfterThat=inputStream.nextLine();
```

You have to store every line before you can do anything with that.
You are assuming that inputStream.nextLine() reads the same line again and again, but each time you use inputStream.nextLine() it reads the next line of the file and reaches the end of the file eventually. That's what is wrong.

You're not understanding the way Scanner works
Use this:

```
if (line.equals("Pets")) {
    String nextLine = inputStream.nextLine();
    if (nextLine.equals("type cat")) {
        initType = "cat";
        System.out.print(initType);
    }
    else if (nextLine.equals("type dog")) {
        initType = "dog";
        System.out.print(initType);
    }
    String lineAfterThat=inputStream.nextLine();
    if (lineAfterThat.equals("size small")) {
            initSize = "small";

        } else if (lineAfterThat.equals("size medium")) {
            initSize = "medium";

        } else if (lineAfterThat.equals("size large")) {
            initSize = "large";

        } else System.out.println("error");
        String nextFirstWord=inputStream.next(); //so that it reads only till the space
        if (nextFirstWord.equals("name")) {
            initName = inputStream.nextLine();

        } else {
            System.out.println("error");
        }
        String ageLineFirstWord = inputStream.next();
        if (ageLineFirstWord .equals("age")) {
            initAge =inputStream.nextInt();
        } else {
            System.out.println("error");
        }
        inputStream.nextLine(); //this is to move the scanner to the nextline
        String doctorLineFirstWord = inputStream.next();
        if (doctorLineFirstWord .equals("doctor")) {
            initDoctor = inputStream.nextLine();
        } else {
            System.out.println("error");
        }
```

Comment: Thankyou, Ill try that and report back

Comment: Happy to help! Cheers✌️

Comment: caterror
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:860)
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1497)
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2161)
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2115)
 at Clinic.readFile(Clinic.java:673)
 at Clinic.run(Clinic.java:98)
 at Clinic.main(Clinic.java:705)

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: This is a mess, I did what you said, and it returns
caterror,
then all of the above exceptions

Comment: you mistake was using inputStream.toString(); you should've used inputStream.nextLine() or inputStream.next() depending on your requirement